# Need some advice with classes in C++, doubly linked list

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm trying to print all the elements of the list, but I'm getting a wrong output.

The code gets 2, 0 and 10, and when I call the procedure "travel_in" it only shows 0, 2.

And have some doubts with my del_start(), it deletes the 0 and not the 2..

What I'm doing wrong?

Compiled in Windows 64bits with Cygwin

### Output

2 0 10 0 2

### Here is the code

```
# include < iostream >

# include < stdio.h >
using namespace std;

template <class clali>
class double_list
{
    protected:
        clali node1;
    clali *listad;
public:
    double_list()//constructor
    {
        listad=NULL;
    }
    void insert_strt(clali node1)
    {
        clali *temp;
        temp=new clali;
        *temp=node1;
        
        //check if list is not empty
        if (listad==NULL)
        {
            listad=temp;
            listad->next=NULL;
            listad->before=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=listad;
            listad->before=temp;
            temp->before=NULL;
            listad=temp;    
        }
    }

    int vertam()
    {
        int res=0;
    clali *temp;
    temp=listad;
    if (temp==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Empty list!"<<endl;
        res=0;
    }
    else
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            res++;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    return res;
    }
    

    void insert_mid(clali node1, int pos)
    {
        int i;
        clali *temp,*temp2;
        temp2=new clali;
        temp=listad;
        if(pos<vertam)
    {
        for(i=1;i<pos;i++)
        temp=temp->next;
        *temp2=node1;
        temp2->next=temp->next;
        temp->before=listad;
        temp->next=temp2;
        
    }
    else
    cout<<"Cant show the data!"<<endl;
    }
    
    clali del_start()
    {
        clali a,*temp;
        a=*listad;
        temp=listad;
        listad=listad->next;
        delete temp;
        return a;
    }
    
    void insert_end(clali node1)
    {
        clali *temp,*temp2;
        temp=listad;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp2=new clali;
    *temp2=node1;
    temp->next=temp2;
    temp2->before=temp;
    temp2->next=NULL;
        
    }
    clali  clear_end()
    {
        clali b,*temp,*temp2;
        int j=1;
        temp=listad;
        do
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            cout<<"Element : "<<j<<endl;
            j++;
        }while(temp->next!=NULL);
        b=*temp;
        temp2=temp->before;
        temp2->next=NULL;
       // delete temp;
        return b;
    }
    void travel_in()
    {
        clali *temp;
        temp=listad;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
        cout<<temp->data<<endl;
        temp=temp->next;
        }
    }

    
};

struct integer
{
int data;
integer*next,*before;
};
typedef struct integer Integer;
int main()
{
    Integer node;
    node.next=NULL;
    node.before=NULL;
    double_list<Integer>  test_list;
    
    test_list.insert_strt(node);
    node.data=2;
    cout<<node.data<<endl;
    test_list.insert_end(node);
    node.data=0;
    cout<<node.data<<endl;
    test_list.insert_end(node);
    node.data=10;
    cout<<node.data<<endl;
test_list.del_start();
    test_list.travel_in();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least one obvious bug. Initial analysis indicates that the `listad` class member is the pointer to the first element in the doubly-linked list. In that case, the following is obviously wrong (reformated for legibility, please indent your code correctly):

```
void insert_mid(clali node1, int pos)
{
    int i;
    clali *temp,*temp2;
    temp2=new clali;
```

The purpose of this class method is, apparently, to insert the new node in the middle of the linked list.

`temp2` is the new node.

```
    temp=listad;

    if(pos<vertam)
    {
        for(i=1;i<pos;i++)
            temp=temp->next;
```

`temp` appears to be the insert position in the middle of the list.

```
        temp->before=listad;
```

For some unclear reason this code attempts to set the `before` pointer of an existing node in the middle of the list to the head of the list. This makes no sense, and is wrong.

Comment: But I don't get it, Ok, I understand ur point, but why it prints the 2 0 10 2? That's my doubt..

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step by step in `main()`.

When you first call `insert_strt()` the argument `node` has garbage value for member `data`. So an `Integer` object with some garbage value for `data` gets inserted at the start of `test_list`. Then you insert `Integer` objects with `data` 2 and 0, respectively, at the end of the list.

Later, you delete the first `clali` object from `test_list` which deletes the object with garbage value in its `data` field. So, after deletion, you have objects with `data` value 2, and 0 in the list in that order.

At the end, you print the list with `travel_in()` but it does not do what you think it does. What it is actually doing is that if the list has at least one element then it prints all but the last element in the list. If the list is empty, it will cause a segmentation fault (in the condition of `while` loop as `temp` would be `NULL`). So it will print: 2 (but your list has 2 and 0).

You can write `travel_in()` as follows.

```
void travel_in()
{
  clali *temp = listad;
  while(temp != NULL)
  {
    cout << temp->data << " ";
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

By the way, comment/remove the `cout` statements in the `main()` function. They may confuse you.